# Higher Order functions from Eloquent JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am learning JavaScript and using the [Eloquent JavaScript](https://www.eloquentjavascript.net/) book by Marijn Haverbeke.  I don't understand how the below higher order function works, specifically how the variables m and n are assigned.

Please advise.

```
function greaterThan(n) {
  return m => m > n;
}
let greaterThan10 = greaterThan(10);
console.log(greaterThan10(11));
// → true
```

I've run the code and proven that it works for when m > n (true) and when m < n (false).

Comment: Parameters are "assigned" when functions are called. Calling `greaterThan` with the parameter `10` assigns it to `n`. `greaterThan` returns a function "enclosing" `n`--it remains `10`. The returned function is called with its own parameter, assigned to `m`. The "magic" you may be missing are **closures** (searchable term).

Answer (score 3):

First of all, there are multiple concepts you need to understand:

- **Function declaration** is a description of what function accepts and how does it behave. In your example `function greaterThan(n) { ... }` and `m => ...` are function declarations.
- **Function invocation** is a request to execute specific function with specific arguments. In you example `greaterThan(10)` is a function invocation.
- **Parameters** are special local variables that a function accepts and can use later. In your example, `n` is a parameter of `greaterThan` function and `m` is a parameter of the inner function.
- **Arguments** are specific values of parameters passed during function invocation.
- **Function scope** is tougher to explain. It kind of a virtual space containing references to all the variables visible in specific function. For example, `greaterThan` sees variable `n` only, but inner `m => m > n` sees both `n` and `m`. That's because of another concept called **closure**.
- **[Closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)** - tldr means that inner function can reference variables from all parent scopes, up to global scope.

---

Now to explaining your case.

```js
function greaterThan(n) {
  return m => m > n;
}
```

This declares a function `greaterThan` with a single parameter `n`.
This function returns a closure - anonymous function with single parameter `m`.

```js
let greaterThan10 = greaterThan(10);
```

This invokes `greaterThan` function with `10` as argument. `greaterThan` returns a closure with `n=10`. E.g:

```js
let greaterThan10 = m => m > 10;
```

And finally

```js
console.log(greaterThan10(11));
```

invokes the function returned by `greaterThan` with `11` as an argument.

E.g. `(m => m > 10)(11)` -> `11 > 10` -> `true`.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `n` is the parameter to `greaterThan()`, so it's assigned when that function is called. The function returns *another* function, one with a parameter called `m`.  That parameter is assigned a value when the returned function is called.

Thus in your example, `n` gets the value 10 when `greaterThan()` is called, and then `m` in the returned function gets the value 11 when that function is called.